# Force Mathematica to simplify an ArcTan[]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I understand that there are many solutions that will produce the same arctangent, nevertheless I really need a simplification:

```
$Assumptions = {w0 > 0, a > 0, G \[Element] Reals}
FullSimplify[ArcTan[E^(-I G w0)]]
```

I want to get out `G w0`

Does anybody know something that will let *Mathematica* simplify this expression?

Attempted solution:

```
FullSimplify[Log[E^(-I G w0)]]
```

Comment: If I Plot[{Re[ArcTan[E^(-I x)]], Im[ArcTan[E^(-I x)]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}] I don't think I see that being just x. And I think your G Real times w0>0 means G w0 is equivalent to just x Real. So I think the reason it might be resisting your attempts to simplify to G w0 is that it just isn't equal. Have you mangled your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplifications work only if you avoid branch cuts of the inverse function. Here I do that for the `ArcTan` function, but using the relation that *I think you meant to prove* (I may have guessed wrong, of course):

```
FullSimplify[
 ArcTan[-I (Exp[2 I x] - 1)/(Exp[2 I x] + 1)], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2]

(* ==> x *)
```

For the second part of the question, how to simplify `Log[E^(-I G w0)]`, the simplest would be a replacement rule, but it may be of interest to try a different approach based on integral transforms (because they automatically make assumptions that we want here, too):

In particular, the Laplace transform (if it has an inverse) can be used to transform an expression `f[x]` back into itself, or into an equivalent, simplified version of itself:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[f[ x], x, t], t, x]

(* ==> f[x] *)

InverseLaplaceTransform[
 LaplaceTransform[Log[E^(-2 I  x)], x, t], t, x]

(* ==> -2 I x *)
```

The first line shows that the composition with the inverse in general leaves the original expression unchanged. Then I apply that to `Log[E^(-2 I  x)]` and get the desired simplification.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know what is conceptually different between the following two expressions:`FullSimplify[Log[Exp[-I x]], -Pi < x < Pi]
FullSimplify[ArcTan[Exp[-I x]], -Pi < x < Pi]`

Comment: They both have branch cuts. The difference is that `ArcTan` has *two* branch points at $\pm i$, while `Log` only has one at 0. In both cases, the unit circle generated by `E^(-2 I  x)` hits these cuts, so *Mathematica* doesn't want to perform the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have entered the wrong equation, but for yours one gets:

```
Simplify@TrigToExp[ArcTan[E^(-I G w0)]]
```

$\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-i e^{-i\ G\ \text{w0}}\right)-\log \left(1+i e^{-i\ G\
   \text{w0}}\right)\right)$