# Simplify $\tan(\arctan(a) - \arctan(b))$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to simplify the expression $\tan(\arctan(a) - \arctan(b))$ to $\tfrac{a-b}{1+a\cdot b}$ (if $b \neq - \tfrac{1}{a}$). Right now, the output of

```
FullSimplify[Tan[ArcTan[a] - ArcTan[b]], {a > 0, b > 0, a < Pi/2, b < Pi/2}]
```

is the same as the input. The assumptions are to assure that $b \neq -\tfrac{1}{a}$ and to give the right branch for the inverse `ArcTan`.

Previous answers suggest the use of `ComplexityFunction`, although I'm not sure how to use that in this case. Is Mathematica able to simplify this?

Comment: Have you seen [Force Mathematica to simplify an ArcTan](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80821/force-mathematica-to-simplify-an-arctan?rq=1) and others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's two possibilities:

```
Simplify[TrigExpand[Tan[ArcTan[a] - ArcTan[b]]]]
```

> ```
> (a - b)/(1 + a b)
> ```

```
FullSimplify[Tan[ArcTan[a] - ArcTan[b]], 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 1000 Count[#, ArcTan[_], Infinity] &)]
```

> ```
> (a - b)/(1 + a b)
> ```